# JQuery On method doesn't work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-on

I got this error in Firefox: TypeError: $("#main-CNTR").on is not a function.
And this code doesn't work at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-CNTR').on('mouseenter','.social_span',function(){
        alert("INSIDE");
    });
    $('#main-CNTR').on('mouseleave','.social_span',function(){
        alert("OUTSIDE");
    });
});
```

The HTML part is this

```
    <span class="social_span"></span>
    <div class="row clearfix" style="display:none;">
        <ul class="social-buttons cf">
            <li>1</li>                                    
        </ul>
    </div>
```

On mouse entering the span a message should be displayed and the next div shown. Obviously the div#main-CNTR is the main content container div and the HTML snippet is repeated several time in the page.

The live method correctly works but not in ie8.

```
$('.social_span').live('mouseenter',function(){
    alert("INSIDE");
});
$('.social_span + .row').live('mouseleave',function(){
    alert("OUTSIDE");
});
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/engine/core8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/engine/ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.li-scroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.reflection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery/plugin/jquery.selectbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you include the `<script>` tags you're using to load jQuery in your page? Make sure you don't have two that are loading different versions of jQuery.

Comment: The strange thing is that I load just one "core8.js" JQuery library. And I cant' get why it tells me is running the 1.6.4 version ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.on()` function was added in jQuery 1.7, so you'll need to make sure you're using that version or higher in order to use `.on()`. From the error you're getting that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like you've got an earlier version. @Davide What is output when you run: `console.log($().jquery)` from within your ready function?

Comment: As I said, I'm using latest JQuery version 1.8.1

Comment: @Davide The error you're saying you're getting suggests that's not the case. jQuery 1.8.1 definitely has the `.on()` function. You've either got an incomplete version being loaded or are loading more than one version of jQuery on your page which is causing conflicts.

Comment: I'm realizing that maybe another version is loading. But I can't get where, that's so strange. Web mysteries.

Comment: I found that the jQuery TOOLS library was loading itself the 1.6.4 jQuery's version. Now 'on' method works in ie8 too.
Moreover I'm using the Socialite.js library (socialitejs.com) and the script Socialite.process(document.getElementsByClassName('.social-buttons')); was ie8-blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work just fine with jQuery 1.8.0:

http://jsfiddle.net/wroniasty/2q2Df/

Comment: I see. I'm thinking it's a JQUery library version problem.

Comment: If you prepare a jsfiddle with a minimum amount of code that demonstrates your error, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I know @wroniasty but it seems to be a JQuery versions problem. I don't know why but it loads two different libraries. The first is the 1.8.1 from google and the other one is 1.6.4...so strange guys

Answer (score 0):

I found that the jQuery TOOLS library was loading itself the 1.6.4 jQuery's version. And now 'on' method works. Hope it will be fine in ie8 too...

Comment: Moreover I'm using the Socialite.js library (http://socialitejs.com) and the script Socialite.process(document.getElementsByClassName('.social-buttons')); was ie8-blocking.